# On an indefinite integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I just had my midterm exam in multivariable calculus and this was one of the final questions, i kinda struggled with. But I'm supposed to find the indefinite integral of:

$$\int\int_{R^{2}}(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

I tried to transform it into a polar coord integral, but I didn't know how to continue, could some one show me or tell me what this would equal to?
$$\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^1_0r^3e^{-r^4}drd\theta$$

Comment: You wrote *indefinite integral* but the integral is definite.  Did you mean improper?

Comment: @SamiShafi as Mattew noted it is an improper integral, note that we need to consider $$\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^{\infty}_0r^3e^{-r^4}drd\theta$$ if the domain consider is all $ \mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: @SamiShafi Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$=\left(\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta\right)\left(\frac {-1}{4}\int _0^1 -4r^3e^{-r^4}dr\right) $$
Let $-r^4=u$ Hence $-4r^3dr=du$
$$=\frac {-\pi}{2} \int_0^{-1} e^u du$$
$$=\frac {-\pi(e-1)}{2e}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $(e^{-r^4})'=-4r^3e^{-r^4}$ apply Fubini, by integrating relatively to $r$ first.

Comment: I would get $e^{-r}^4=$  $e^{-1}^4 - e^0 $ $=\int^{2\pi}_{0} e^1 - 1? d\theta$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\int\int_{R^{2}}(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x^2+y^2)^2}
=\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^{\infty}_0r^3e^{-r^4}drd\theta=2\pi\int^{\infty}_0r^3e^{-r^4}dr
$$

and

$$(e^{-r^4})'=-4r^3e^{-r^4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: by substitution:
$$t=r^4; dt=4r^3dr$$